# Changing date in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning React and currently dealing with Material-UI Date Picker but I'm unable to change the date from the calendar.

**The current state I'm using**

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ ...newTripStateData })
```

I have all state data in that ojbect (newTripStateData) but when I try to access and change the departureDate which is equal to(new Date) using the below function; it's not changing. What am I doing wrong?

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    state.departureDate = date;
    setState(state.departureDate)

  }
```

**Date Picker**

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider  utils={DateFnsUtils}>
              <KeyboardDatePicker
                className={styles.inputs}
                disableToolbar
                inputVariant="outlined"
                format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                error={state.departureDateErrorStatus}
                margin="normal"
                id="date-picker-inline-1"
                label="Departure Date"
                selected={state.departureDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                KeyboardButtonProps={{
                  'aria-label': 'change date'
                }}
              />
              <FormHelperText
              error={state.departureDateErrorStatus}
              className={styles.helper_text_error}
              >
                {state.departureDateError}
              </FormHelperText>
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

**Material UI Error in the Chrome dev tools**

```
Material-UI: a component is changing the controlled value state of SelectInput to be uncontrolled.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code (how you're using the Picker). Right away, `state.departureDate = date;` this is wrong. It directly mutates state, and then you only update the state with a nested portion of the original.

Comment: @BrianThompson, I have edited the post for elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change `state` like `state.departureDate = date`. You have to use `setState` to change it.

You can directly do:

```js
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      departureDate: date
    })
}
```

Comment: can you make a minimal repro on https://codesandbox.io? this should work perfectly fine i think :)

Comment: deadcoder0904, please allow me to ask you one more question. I want to change (departureDate, arrivalDate, returnDate) but when I do as below, it doesn't even select the departue data: 

``const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setState({...state, departureDate, returnDate, arrivalDate : (date)})
  }``

Comment: You can't set multiple object key values like that. you have to assign each one individually.

Comment: Brian Thompson, is this what you mean?

``const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setState({...state, departureDate: date})
    setState({...state, arrivalDate: date})
    setState({...state, returnDate: date})
  }``
It is taking the value of the 3rd setState.

Comment: No I mean: `setState({ ...state, departureDate: date, returnDate: date, arrivalDate: date })`

Comment: yep do what @BrianThompson said above

Answer (score 1):

There is no `selected` prop according to the [docs](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker).

Change `selected={state.departureDate}` to `value={state.departureDate}`. Along with the function updates described in @deadcoder0904's answer:

```js
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    departureDate: date
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont set the state directly, use only the setState method. Also it is better to create a state variable instead of pushing the whole state into one:

```
...
const [date, setDate] = React.useState()
...
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setDate(date)
  }
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the state structure from the question. But you are correct about not setting it directly.

Comment: The problem is that I have the state has so much data that I had to create a separate file and then import it, and then set that state like that. I didn't want to has a thousand lines of code as I have 500 already. 

So, setting the changing the state for every property seemed stupid to me yet what I'm doing right now requires me to use react hooks.